# Bullying group work

Tags: bullying

I am working with a group of 3 people, we are only students and we are doing a project. At our last meeting they accused me that I am liar because I missed some meetings because I was lazy and tired and not sick. 
When I was at the first meeting they talked in their native language which is different than mine. The situation was frustrating for me since the beginning. They delegated to me a task that is too hard for me because was the last task to do. I tried to do my job but I had a lot of trouble and I ask some suggestions. They didn't answer me at the beginning but during our last meeting they told me that it was my only task to do and If I have some problem to solve it, is not their fault because they are not Teachers.
Finally, they want to give me a bad grade throuh peer evaluation because according to them I am liar and I didn't solve my task.
The project is almost finish, we will have the presentation in a few days.I spend many hours for the task and now there is nothing that I can do, I was stuck with some calculus. I don't have any motivation to work with  them because they think that I am liar and they were aggressive with me. One of them contacted me only for messagge to tell me that they will give me a bad grade, she didn't say anything in person. They decided to implement the peer evaluation at the end of the project and it is unfair.

I was sick for about 1 month and I still taking medicine because I haven't recovered yet.  I have the proof of it and all the cerfiticates that the hospital gave to me. The school knows that I have health problems.
What should I do?
Do you think that it can be considered a form of bullying?

I talked with the tutor yesterday and she suggested me to write a letter to the teacher and explain the situation because if they want to give me a bad grade I can do extra work to increase the grade but the teacher has to decide. I don't know if it is a good idea to write a letter to the teacher because I am adult and I used to solve the problem with my team members  face to face but this time it seems impossible and I am feeling really bad

I am sorry for my english but I am not native. I am feeling really bad for this situation and even though is not a problem in a "workplace"  I would like to have some suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a workplace issue. This is an issue within a student work group - and so the solution is better advised by people more familiar with academic/classroom scenarios

Comment: The only thing I can advise is talk to your tutor, or course supervisor, or lecturer who set this group project

Comment: Are you at university?

Comment: yes, I am  at university.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. They want to use the peer evaluation to give me less points regarding mine contribuition during our project and as  a result I will have a bad grade

Comment: I am still sick honestly. I am tacking antibiotics. They started the project about 6 weeks ago and at that time I was sick, They organized the first 2 meetings without me, When I was at the first meeting they have finished almost the work, they decided what task to do and what task delegate to me. There were only one task to do and I worked on it a lot of time but it was difficult for me to understand how to do the calculation and this is the reason why I didn't complete it and yes, I am still sick because I have an infection

Comment: @Ben - So talk to your professor.  It is not the student's fault you are sick.  Now their treatment of you is something else entirely.  However, we all have to push through things, and sometimes complete tasks that are difficult.  They had no control over when the project started, it is not their fault, you are sick.  You might not like the alternative to a group project, and that is, turning a project in by yourself in an accelerated timeline.

Comment: yeah..I know. This is not my first group work. I always help people if they are not able to complete a task due to lack knowledge or different background.  But they assigned me to me the only difficult task of the project and they did the most theoretical and easier ones. What hurted me the most is that they told me that I am liar.

Comment: When they said that you lied, why didn't you show them the medical certificates? Also, peer evaluation goes both ways, so in that evaluation you can demonstrate (with facts) that you were ill, excluded from project planning, and set up to fail. Show that you tried your best in the face of adversity, and highlight how helpful and supportive your colleagues weren't.

Answer (score 5):

Speak to your personal tutor. Immediately.

They might not be able to solve the problem for you but they are the best person to advise you what to steps to take to minimise any impact on your grades.

There are lots of reasons to believe that this will go well for you but you need to take the right steps.

Comment: I talked with the tutor yesterday and she suggested me to write a letter to the teacher and explain the situation because if they want to overgrade me I can do extra work to increase the grade but the teacher has to decide. I don't know if it is a good idea to write a letter to the teacher because I am adult and I used to solve the problem with my team members and face to face but this time it seems impossible and I am feeling really bad

Comment: If your tutor suggested this course of action then you should probably take it.

Comment: You can still try to work with your group. This is unlikely to damage your case and if things work out then maybe you will solve the problem in the way that you would like to. Probably the best way to do this would be to actively solve some problem or produce a piece of work that the group can use. However, you want to make the course teacher aware of the situation to defend yourself in case: 1) it doesn't work out even though you tried or 2) you complete your task but the group decides to complain about you anyway.

Comment: @Ben - It is clear based on the description that the only way you will get a good grade from your group, is if you finish your task, but I have been on the other end of a group project.  Where I had to do all the work that wasn't completed, due to members of the team, not being able to finish the work.  I worked through colds during those group projects also, but I had to complete the work, to finish the project and pass the course.  So either talk to the professor, or finish the work, we all get sick and sometimes are forced to push through it.

Comment: they want to evaluate me in any case because even though I will finish the task they did more than me. The only positive things is that if I finish my task I can talk 2 minutes during the presentation instead of saying anything but my grade will be bad in any case.  I was in group works when I did the job for others but I have never complained because this is "only" a  University

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. Option 1 is to go to the group leader and have a 1-on-1 to express your frustrations and explain calmly how your medical problems are an issue and you will try to attend as many meetings as possible and contribute when you can. You should have also let your team know in the beginning.

The other option is to ask to be reassigned away from this group though that may be harder

I don’t think it is bullying and more of the group expressing their frustration with you. Communication and perception is key. I think you can get through this though you don’t want to be making a lot of excuses over it.

Comment: thank you.  Unfortunately there is no leader in our group. The last meeting was yesterday . They knew that I was sick but they didn't believe me, I asked them many times to postpone one meeting because I had very high fever and they told me that it wasn't possible.

Comment: There must be a de facto leader maybe the one with the strongest personality

Comment: The one with the strongest personality wants to overgrade me

Comment: I talked with the tutor yesterday and  she suggested me to write a letter to the teacher and explain the situation because if they want to overgrade me I can do extra work to increase the grade but the teacher has to decide. I don't know if it is a good idea to write a letter to the teacher because I am adult and I used to solve the problem with my team members and face to face but this time it seems impossible and I am feeling really bad

Answer (score 0):

You should have right away told your fellow students to come with you to the teacher where he would corroborate your claims because you handed all official paperwork from the hospital to the school.
That would have shut them up.

Mind you, they quite possibly may have been threatened by a student foreign to them or had some other personal issue with you.

**NOW**
Inform your tutor about the situation and refer to your evidence of being sick.
Emphasize that they didn't believe you and voiced their intent to retaliate with a bad evaluation for what they assume was lying and lazyness.

*This should turn the tables and actually cast them in a very bad light.*

Comment: yes,I will do that. They have just told me that they want to present the project without me and I am feeling really bad because I spend many hours to work on the task that they assigned to me.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not only the group work, I think that there are some personal issue because they are the first group here that want to use the peer evaluation in the entire school.

Comment: @Ben Tell your teacher that they intend to exclude you from the presentation and inquire if they a) cand do that b) you should or shouldn't take part and c) if / how it will impact your grade. You probably should also ask to get a personal assignment to make up for this and prove your abilities....on a side note, I really think peer review is a bad idea. Your situation is a perfect contra example why it could be toxic to team dynamics (not just in schools) and individual well being  professionally and personally.

Comment: They told me that as I didn't do any slides, I don't have to present anything.  I have 4 exams next week, I don't want to loose time with these kind of people.They aren't smart because all the group will receive a bad grade because of this problem. Unfortunately the presentation is on Monday so I don't have time to have a response before the presentation but I will contact the teacher. I was checking my messages and I noticed that since the beginning they didn't answer my message in our group chat.

Comment: yes, peer evaluation is a bad idea but noone in the school is using it. Only people in my group against me and..there are many many people here that don't do anythng for projects and presentations but I have never heard someone using it

Comment: @Ben I see.You should show up anyways to the presentation and speak with your teacher beforehand.Get your side of the story in writing and hand it to your teacher if you haven't already informed them about this whole drama. If the teacher wants you to be in the presentation,ask if you can have a few words at the beginning and make a list now of what you contributed and your health issues.inform the team in the last second that your teacher vetoed and wants you there and speak first.don't bother with them anymore, other than showing initiative to still be part of the team.keep proof of this.

Comment: thank you  very much. I will do what  you suggested  to me. thanks..

Comment: @Ben regarding peer evalutation. hmm in that case it's not official and should have no merit at all unless your univeristy allows it officially as an option.Check with your teacher and administration if they even are allowed to do a peer review.Since your grades may take a big hit and if you're sure that you're legally in the right you could also take formal steps against the students and / or the grade if your teacher turns out to be incooperative and / orsharing the teams evaluation of you. That obviously will be a battle for another day and you'll need legal support.

Comment: @Ben you're welcome, fingers crossed you can salvage the situation.

Comment: This is a small University and all the students are Erasmus/Exchange students and usually they don't care to loose time by doing this unuseful things. The peer evaluation is transparent, this means that my group members will write the percentage of contribuition of each members in a sheet of paper and each of one has to sign it.I won't sign it, I will write that I am against it and I will explain the reasons. So, it's official but noone take care of it.Noone is using the peer evaluation and the teacher haven't said anything until now. The University's Director  and teacher don't care about it.

Comment: @Ben yeah.don't sign anything.before you explain your reasons inform yourself what the university statutes say about peer evaluation.if there is no mentioning of it, state that to your knowledge it isn't accepted as official university procedure.don't open new,unrelated discussions with your teacher, university staff or the team!!so, ideally you shouldn't even state your reasons why you don't sign it unless asked by your teacher or staff.DON'T explain yourself to the team and DON'T get into ANY ARGUMENTS with them.they're trying to get more ammo anyways.remain civil and examplary in behaviour.

Comment: I asked to the program coordinator and she told me that the peer evaluation is compulsory but as I told you  noone takes care of the rules here.  The program coordinator told me to write in the sheet of contribuition (peer evaluation) that I am against it. She is not in the position to tell me to do not sign it because there is the peer evaluation even though noone have used it until now.

Comment: @Ben ah,well then do that. but try not to say why you're against it.that is better for a private chat with your teacher as it relates to the team being hostile towards you.try to find indicators for this btw. in your written communications and chats you had as well, where it becomes clear that they are negative towards you personally.Thing is,you are excused by doctors and you informed the university about your health issues.the fact that the team reacted this poorly is not on you and nothing you can change now but is worth mentioning and documenting to demonstrate the climate within it.

Comment: @Ben actually, come to think of it, maybe you could include that you were sick. I'm not a lawyer, so have no idea if this is legally speaking better or not. if you have a chance to ask someone do so before inclunding it.

Comment: ok, yes. I have all the messages when I send them my tasks and noone answered.  But the worst thing is when they told me that I am liar and I don't have any proof of it. What hurts me the most is not the peer evaluation but the fact they don't trust me because they have assumed that I am liar

Comment: no, you are right. I don't have to explain the reasons in detail because I will explain them in the email that I will send tomorrow to the teacher

Comment: @Ben As I understood,you have medical documents reflecting that you were sick,that is all the proof you need.Should have been enough for the team and shows their attitude towards you.As has been said though,you'll many times in your life have to work through illness(unless life threatening),keep that in mind for the future,especially when your livelyhood will be on the line.In the letter elaborate how bad your illness was and if you took medication that impedes mental capacity.I just realized btw.,comments are not a place for extended discussions (; I wish you good luck!

Comment: yes, I know. I worked on presentation also when I was sick but this time something goes wrong with them. I worked on about 15  presentations in this year and I have never had a problem like this. I don't know why they want to give me a bad grade. it seems that is more important my grade than the entire presentation.